# 2D Array printing on first row

Tags: java

For some reason it prints "*" nine times on one row. Instead of a 3x3 of *.

Should also be noted that the main function simply runs the displayBoard function and would not change the output.

```
  public class TicTacToeTwoPlayer {
   static final int SIZE = 3;
   /*
      Here:
      Declare a 2-d character array called board with SIZE rows and SIZE columns.
      Be sure to use the static modifier in the declaration
   */
   static char[][] board = new char [SIZE][SIZE];

   static final char PLAYER1 = 'X';
   static final char PLAYER2 = 'O';
   static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void initializeBoard() {
       /*
          Here:
          Initialize each position of the board array to a space character.
       */
       for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
           for(int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) board[row][col] = ' ';
        
       }    
   }

   public static void displayBoard() {
       /*
        Here:
        Complete this method so that it displays the tic-tac-toe board
        to the screen. If a board position is available, that is, if it is
        a space, output an asterisk followed by a space ("* ".)
       */
       for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
               if (board[row][col] == ' ') {
                    System.out.print("* ");
               } else {
                   System.out.print(board[row][col]);
               }
           } 
       }
            
        
       System.out.println("Board is: ");
    
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing a newline after each row:

```java
public static void displayBoard() {
    for (int row=0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] == ' ') {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
        }
        // print a device-independent newline here after each row
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Board is: "); 
 }
```

Comment: I shouldn't need to right? It is a 2D array. That might work but I believe something is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: `I shouldn't need to right?` ... Why would you think this?  `print` does _not_ print newlines automatically.  So either you need to explicitly print a CR?LF after each row, or call `println` as I have done above.

Comment: I was under the impression from looking at a few examples of 2D arrays that it was unnecessary. I think its because most examples i looked at were arrays of strings that were manually formatted in the creation of the array.